# zabbix error The frontend does not match Zabbix database

Tags: zabbix

install zabbix at `Configure DB connection` error `The frontend does not match Zabbix database.`
i use mysql 
What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that the version of the Zabbix database does not match what Zabbix frontend is expecting. For instance, if you are upgrading from Zabbix 2.2 to Zabbix 3.0, then you will get a similar message (together with the current database version and the expected database version) until you upgrade the database (this is done by simply running the new version of Zabbix server).

In this particular case, if you are installing for the  first time, then you probably have not imported `schema.sql`, `images.sql`, and `data.sql` files yet. In that case, please consult ["Installation from sources"](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/installation/install) and ["Database creation scripts"](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/install/db_scripts) sections in the online Zabbix documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much!According to your method.I installed it to succeed

Comment: I had same issue with all imported schemas but with wrong owner. He must be same as in connection settings

Answer (score 2):

In case you have been using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to do a new install of Zabbix 3.0  then you should first populate the database with the sql file provided in /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql/create.sql. After that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

installation error: frontend does not match Zabbix database

[read more here:](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/install/db_scripts)

drop existing zabbix db

then

```
shell> mysql -u<username> -p<password>
mysql> create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
mysql> quit;
shell> mysql -u<username> -p<password> zabbix < database/mysql/schema.sql
# stop here if you are creating database for Zabbix proxy
shell> mysql -u<username> -p<password> zabbix < database/mysql/images.sql
shell> mysql -u<username> -p<password> zabbix < database/mysql/data.sql
```

after that step 3 is ok...

Answer (score 0):

I was upgrading a **debian** distro from **7** to **8** that had **Zabbix** installed. When this error appeared, what I did was to *install* the `zabbix-server-mysql` service by typing:

```
apt-get install zabbix-server-mysql
```

And that solved the problem.